# Can't play HLS stream in Ice cream Sandwich

Tags: android, http-live-streaming

I am an android developer,
I am playing HLS stream in in my project.
Following is code:

```
    private String path = "http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear1/prog_index.m3u8";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    VideoView mVideoView;
    setContentView(R.layout.videoview);
    mVideoView = new VideoView(this);
    mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
    mVideoView.start();
    setContentView(mVideoView);
}
```

Also taken permission for INTERNET.

It runs in 4.0.4 fine,
While It shows message in Emulator and device with android 4.0.3 and 4.0
And also shows "error (1, -2147483648)"

*Please help me to run HLS smoothly on all android devices with Android 4.x.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Different devices and versions of Android have different support for A/V codecs. I guess you just got unlucky with your devices. Its normal to not work in the emulator, because the emulator doesn't include the AVC and AAC codecs which are provided by the drivers on Android devices.

One thing you could try is to change the http:// to httplive:// as was required in some 3.x releases. But since you're using 4.x, I wouldn't expect that to help.

Comment: Thanks vipw for reply, Is there any way to play HLS stream smoothly on android version 4.x or 4.x.x (Icecreamsandwitch or earlier)? I used vitamio plugin, but stream is played with much flickering, and tried HTML5, but not succeed.